# How should one respond to "お大事に"?

Tags: set-phrases, expressions

I came across a situation where I went to a volunteer class wearing a mask since I have a cough. My sensei told me "お大事に", and I did not know what to reply.

In this case, should I just say "はい"?
Or is there a more appropriate response?

Comment: Maybe ありがとうございました? :)

Comment: @WenzelJakob Make that ありがとうござい*ます*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most common reply among us native speakers would be a simple 「ありがとうございます。」.

「はい」 would sound pretty strange.  You could say 「はい、ありがとうございます。」, though.